# Requested Resource is not available while submitting jsp

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have been trying this simple example but am stuck at this error that happens when I submit the JSP page. I've tried all the suggestions given earlier, but still the get same error. Below is the code:

Hello.jsp

```
<form name="formAction" action="HelloServlet" method="GET">
Login Name:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="Password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

HelloServlet.java

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // my code
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Login.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please help me out. I am using JBoss and I've checked that all my folder structures are correct.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

`<url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>`

`<form name="formAction" action="HelloServlet" method="GET">`
url pattern and form action are different.

Use `<url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>`

Comment: Hey thanks. I changed it to above URL pattern and it worked. But my doubt is <url-pattern> tag indicates the jsp page rite?? then why should i specify the HelloServlet instead of Hello as Hello is jsp that user is hitting.

Comment: <url-pattern> tag indicates what is the url of httprequest not jsp. Ie ie what you see in your browser url box.